# NSDateFormatter.dateFromString returns nil ("yyyy-MM-dd" to NSDate)

Tags: string, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nslocale

Having a problem with NSDateFormatter.

So I have a date string formatted `"yyyy-MM-dd"`, for example 2015-09-22.
However when I pass this into NSDateFormatter.dateFromString, the method returns nil. My code is as follows:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let dateAsNSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(payload.objectForKey("messageExpiry") as! String)
```

From the debugger console at a breakpoint just above this code:

```
po payload.objectForKey("messageExpiry") as! String

"2015-09-31"
```

I have explored other questions similar to this but am as of yet still unable to fix this problem.
Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: This should work for "2015-09-22" (and it does in my test). For "2015-09-31", `nil` is returned because September has only 30 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct and produces the expected result e.g. for
the input string "2015-09-22". For the input "2015-09-31" however,
`nil` is returned because that is an invalid date: September has
only 30 days.

You can set

```
dateFormatter.lenient = true
```

and then "2015-09-31" is accepted and treated as "2015-10-01".
But you should check first *why* `payload.objectForKey("messageExpiry")`
returns an invalid date.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I was that stupid! For this example payload.objectForKey("messageExpiry") was being set manually by me elsewhere so I was to blame for the incorrect value. Easily done I suppose... Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "2015-09-29"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let dateAsNSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str)
print(dateAsNSDate)
// -> "Optional(2015-09-29 07:00:00 +0000)\n"
```

So that would appear to work. Looks like you just got too many days in your month, so it wasn't a valid date! :)

Comment: Thank you! What a stupid mistake haha, easily done I suppose!